# Is ther is a way to run a function after i navigate back from screen in flutter like Navigator.pop(context)

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Is ther is a way to run a function after i navigate back from screen in flutter like Navigator.pop(context)

run a function after i navigate back from screen in flutter like Navigator.pop(context);
ps: i dnt want to use navigator.push(..).then